# Exiting Shell Script from if...else

Tags: ksh, exit

I have a shell script which I want to exit based on the value of a variable `ERROR_COUNT`. I can either write

```
if [ ${ERROR_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "Exiting unsuccessfully";
    exit 1;
fi
echo "Exiting successfully";
exit;
```

or

```
if [ ${ERROR_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "Exiting unsuccessfully";
    exit 1;
else
    echo "Exiting successfully";
    exit;
fi
```

Is there any problem with either of the approaches?

Comment: As far as I understand the functionality there shuldn't be problems with the given approaches.

Answer (score 3):

There is no technical difference between the two ways of writing the branches in terms of what would happen. It's a matter of style and personal preference.

Some developers dislike having an unconditional exit in the `else` branch of an if statement if the first branch is exiting.

I would probably write the code as

```
if [ "$ERROR_COUNT" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'There were errors' >&2
    exit 1
fi
# echo 'No errors' >&2
```

Note the removed semicolons, the quoted variable expansion, and the removed last `exit` (which is implicit at the end of the script. I changed the test to `-ne 0` from `-gt 0` because it's clearer (at least to me).

I've also changed the output of the two diagnostic messages so that they go to the standard error stream (and improved them in a way that would be more useful to the user).  It is debatable whether the last `echo` should be there at all since there is really nothing to report other than successful execution (I commented it out).

Comment: Why were the semicolons removed?

Comment: @Nitish Semicolons are command delimiters, just like newlines.  In almost every case where you have a semicolon, you can replace it with a newline. Note that I also _introduced_ a semicolon to get the `then` on the same line as the `if`.